# Jackson сustom Serializers/Deserializers

Tags: android, java

Где я сделал не правильно?
при дебагинге происходит следующее:
module.addDeserializer
static class JsonDeserializer
mapper.registerModule(module)
return mapper;

Внутри static class JsonDeserializer ничего делать не хочет.....

```
 public class MyJsonWrapper
 {

public static ObjectMapper getMyJson()
{        
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

    module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
    module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());

    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
}

static class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{

    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        try {

        String s = jp.getText().replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");

        if (s.equals("")) return null;

        boolean isDateBefore1970 = false;

        .............

        if (isDateBefore1970)
            return new Date(-Long.valueOf(s) - offset * 60 * 1000);
        else
            return new Date(Long.valueOf(s) + offset * 60 * 1000);

        }catch (JsonMappingException e){                
            return null;
        }

    }
}

static class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {           
        jgen.writeString("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю вроде все написано правильно... Хотя попробуйте объявить класс `JsonDateDeserializer` как `public static`, а еще лучше вынесите его в отдельный (невложенный) класс

Comment: Спасибо! попробую